# I am trying to save an SKLabelNode which is the highscore label but it doesn't work. Also tried UserDefaults

Tags: swift

I am trying to save high sore in the form of sklabelnode using UserDefaults but it doesn't work. Every time I close and open the app the highscore is gone.

I have tried UserDefaults.

```
func afterCollision(){

    let highScore = "highScore"
    if gameSettings.highScore < score{
        gameSettings.highScore = score
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.synchronize()
        defaults.integer(forKey: highScore)
       //I tried using this. 

    }
```

I expected the highscore to be saved but it is lost after I restart the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no attempt to save anything in UserDefaults. You read a value and ignore the result. You need to set the new value.

```
if gameSettings.highScore < score {
    gameSettings.highScore = score
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "highScore")
}
```

When your app starts you can load the high score:

```
gameSettings.highScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScore")
```